# NullPointerException while calling function that print values of full multidimensional array

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, nullpointerexception, tic-tac-toe

guys
I'm trying to build Tic-Tac-Toe from scratch by using java, I'm aware it's not may be perfect but I will try anyway!
I wrote a function that should printing the board when I'm calling it but it's gives me NullPointerException idk why tbh

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
class Task_3{
    static char[][] board;
    static void checkWinner(){
        String v=null;
        for(int p=0;p<8;p++){
            switch(p){
                case 0:
                    v=String.valueOf(board[0][0]+board[0][1]+board[0][2]);
                    break;
                case 1:
                    v=String.valueOf(board[1][0]+board[1][1]+board[1][2]);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    v=String.valueOf(board[2][0]+board[2][1]+board[2][2]);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    v=String.valueOf(board[0][0]+board[1][0]+board[2][0]);
                    break;
                case 4:
                    v=String.valueOf(board[0][1]+board[1][1]+board[2][1]);
                    break;
                case 5:
                    v=String.valueOf(board[0][2]+board[1][2]+board[2][2]);
                    break;
                case 6:
                    v=String.valueOf(board[0][0]+board[1][1]+board[2][2]);
                    break;
                case 7:
                    v=String.valueOf(board[0][2]+board[1][1]+board[2][0]);
                    break;
            }
            if (v.equals("XXX")){
                System.out.println("X is The Winner!");
            }else if(v.equals("OOO")){
                System.out.println("O is The Winner!");
            }else{
                System.out.println("Tie");
            }
        }
    }
    static void printBoard()
    {
        System.out.println("|---|---|---|");
        System.out.println("| " + board[0][0] + " | "
                           + board[0][1] + " | " + board[0][2]
                           + " |");
        System.out.println("|-----------|");
        System.out.println("| " + board[1][0] + " | "
                           + board[1][1] + " | " + board[1][2]
                           + " |");
        System.out.println("|-----------|");
        System.out.println("| " + board[2][0] + " | "
                           + board[2][1] + " | " + board[2][2]
                           + " |");
        System.out.println("|---|---|---|");
    }
    public static void main (String[] args) {
    int pos=0, xoro=1;
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    char[][] board = new char[3][3];
    board[0][0]=1;
    board[0][1]=2;
    board[0][2]=3;
    board[1][0]=4;
    board[1][1]=5;
    board[1][2]=6;
    board[2][0]=7;
    board[2][1]=8;
    board[2][2]=9;
    printBoard();
    pos = sc.nextInt();
    switch(pos){
        case 1:
            if (xoro % 2 == 0)
                board[0][0]='O';
                else
                    board[0][0]='X';
                xoro++;
                for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
                System.out.println(board[i][j]);
            break;
        case 2:
            if (xoro % 2 == 0)
            board[0][1]='O';
                else
                    board[0][1]='X';
                xoro++;
            break;
        case 3:
            if (xoro % 2 == 0)
            board[0][2]='O';
                else
                    board[0][2]='X';
                xoro++;
            break;
        case 4:
            if (xoro % 2 == 0)
            board[1][0]='O';
                else
                    board[1][0]='X';
                xoro++;
            break;
        case 5:
            if (xoro % 2 == 0)
            board[1][1]='O';
                else
                    board[1][1]='X';
                xoro++;
            break;
        case 6:
            if (xoro % 2 == 0)
            board[1][2]='O';
                else
                    board[1][2]='X';
                xoro++;
            break;
        case 7:
            if (xoro % 2 == 0)
            board[2][0]='O';
                else
                    board[2][0]='X';
                xoro++;
            break;
        case 8:
            if (xoro % 2 == 0)
            board[2][1]='O';
                else
                    board[2][1]='X';
                xoro++;
            break;
        case 9:
            if (xoro % 2 == 0)
            board[2][2]='O';
                else
                    board[2][2]='X';
                xoro++;
            break;
    }
    }
}
```

and this is the error I got

```
|---|---|---|
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Task_3.printBoard(Task_3.java:46)
    at Task_3.main(Task_3.java:72)

Process completed.
```

tbh I don't know what seems what be the problem also I'm not that professional in java so sorry if it's was to basic. Thank you guys.. have a nice day.

Comment: Do you initialize the board array anywhere before using it?

Comment: btw guys its not complete yet but I will do it after finding a solution for this problem

Comment: Ah, you are *shadowing* the board variable by declaring it twice. Yes, the variable *with the same name* is initialized in the main method, but this is not the same board variable that you are using elsewhere.

Comment: More importantly, you absolutely *must* learn the general steps used to debug any NullPointerException (NPE) because if you continue programming, you will encounter these beasts again and again. Please read fully the answer in the duplicate used to close your question. Feel free to ask any questions about that answer if it confuses you.

Comment: So, in the main method, change `char[][] board = new char[3][3];` to `board = new char[3][3];` Do you see how these lines are different? The second example removes the `char[][] board` variable declaration statement. More importantly, do you understand why this matters? Look up variable shadowing for more on this.

Comment: yes I did before calling the printBoard(), that's why im confused about it

Comment: No, you did not. Please read or re-read my comments

Comment: You're welcome, but again most important, do you see why the code changes that I recommended in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68146136/nullpointerexception-while-calling-function-that-print-values-of-full-multidimen?noredirect=1#comment120442039_68146136) were made? And do you understand now why the NullPointerException was thrown by your code?

Comment: Again, this variable: `static char[][] board;`, is *not the same* as this one: `char[][] board = new char[3][3];` You have to really understand this to move forward.

Comment: yes it did, there is a different between initializing and declaring & also I need to read the explanation about NPE you recommended to me. thanks